# Send files from media library with reactjs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, media

I have a chat, it is done in REACTJS + nodejs, everything works perfectly, but I want to implement a media library type function, where the person will be able to choose the photos that are available in the system, for example:

I have a page where I upload files, and list them in a table.

On the chat page, where I send messages, when I click the attach file button, the windows window opens normally so that the image can be uploaded and sent.

I would like that when I clicked on this button, a modal would be opened and these images that are available in the system would be listed and that could be selected and sent in the chat.

The modal listing the images in the chat I was able to open it, I just can't get past it, make the selected image sent, I don't know if I would need a callback function or something.

Page where the files are listed:

[image: Página onde mostra os arquivos]

Chat page with modal open:

[image: Página do chat]

I would like that when you click on any image of the modal, it would be sent to the chat.

Part of the code responsible for uploading and sending the file:

```
const handleChangeMedias = (e) => {
if (!e.target.files) {
  return;
}

const selectedMedias = Array.from(e.target.files);
setMedias(selectedMedias);  };

<input
          multiple
          type="file"
          id="upload-button"
          disabled={loading || recording || ticketStatus !== "open"}
          className={classes.uploadInput}
          onChange={handleChangeMedias}
        />
        <label htmlFor="upload-button">
          <IconButton
            aria-label="upload"
            component="span"
            onClick={handleOpenContactModal}
            disabled={loading || recording || ticketStatus !== "open"}
          >
            <AttachFileIcon className={classes.sendMessageIcons} />
          </IconButton>
        </label>
```

Thanks id advanced !

I can create the page to upload the files and I can display these files in a modal on the chat page, now I am not able to select and send any of these files to the chat.

Obs: The functionality of uploading and sending files from the computer to the chat works correctly, I can select the file and send.

Comment: what is the modal code?

Comment: I'll edit the question with modal code